# Strange behavior in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am getting strange behavior, below is the jquery ajax call to my page.

Actually when my page is loading it has got two dropdowns from where it calls below ajax request for both the dropdowns, so two calls to same page.

```
  //alert("Test");
    var serviceReq = "http://localhost:2853/jsonproxy/jsonprxy.aspx"; 
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceReq,
        //type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "airportXML",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
            //alert("data" + data);
            x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                document.write(x[i].nodeName);                        
                document.write("<br />");
            }

            //alert(oData);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + "---" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that it never goes inside success so I never get this //alert("data" + data); it always goes to error saying "parsererror:airportxml is not a function" and I can gurantee the response returned is perfect JSON.

The strange behavior comes if I comment this line jsonpCallback: "airportXML", Jquery give default callback i.e. something jquery12121212_2323232 and everything works fine, however I don't want this as I am looking to have cache call for this

One more strange thing, if I put alert (//alert("Test");) before this call and everything works perfect for me without commenting jsonpCallback: "airportXML" and I get success alert fine.

I think my call is not getting full time to be completed.

Please suggest!!

Comment: The `airportXML` function _is_ defined, right? With the same case?

Comment: yes airportxml is a callback function for my jsonp call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to resolve above issue, I need to use

`async: false,` for my first call, so that my next call get completed.

Please suggest on this.

EDIT: Does JSNOP crossdomain call allows sysncronous calls?

Thanks.